# Jasmine (Karma) test failing with $rootScope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a function in my controller that first watches for a dictionary to be loaded before it takes any action.

The problem i am getting is that my test fails because the watch doesn't appear to run.

My Controller Function

```
function setPageTitle(title) {
        $rootScope.$watch('dictionary', function(dictionary) {
            if (dictionary) {
                if ($location.$$path != '/dashboard') {
                    $rootScope.pageTitle = $rootScope.dictionary.pageTitles[title] || $rootScope.dictionary.pageTitles.dashboard || 'Dashboard';
                } else {
                    $rootScope.pageTitle = $rootScope.dictionary.pageTitles.dashboard || 'Dashboard';
                }                    
            }
        });
    }
```

My Test...

```
describe('AppController function', function() {

var rootScope, scope, $location, $window, controller, createController, cacheFactory, toastr;

beforeEach(module('mockedDashboard'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller, _$location_, _$window_, _toastr_, _$timeout_) {
    $location = _$location_;
    $window = _$window_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    toastr = _toastr_;

    createController = function() {
        return $controller('AppController', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    };
    controller = createController();
}));

// We are using CacheFactory in this project, when running multiple tests on the controller
// we need to destroy the cache for each test as the controller is initialized for each test.
afterEach(inject(function(_CacheFactory_) {
    cacheFactory = _CacheFactory_;
    cacheFactory.destroy('defaultCache');
}));

describe('setPageTitle()', function() {

    it('should update the $rootScope.pageTitle', function() {


        scope.setPageTitle('logIn');

        scope.$apply();

        expect(rootScope.pageTitle).toBe('LOG IN');

    });
});
});
```

the failure message

> Expected undefined to be 'LOG IN'

`rootScope.pageTitle` is never set because the watch doesn't run when the test calls the function. How can i get around this?

I tried `scope.$apply()` which i read should trigger the $watch, but it still doesn't work.

**EDIT**
I tried using the done function, however the test still fails because rootScope.pageTitle still appears to remain undefined. 3000ms should be ample time for this to work, usually this is done in less that 500ms. (i also know that the code works because this test is being written too late)

```
    describe('setPageTitle()', function() {

    it('should update the $rootScope.pageTitle', function(done) {

        scope.setPageTitle('logIn');

        scope.$apply();

        setTimeout(function() {
            // console.log('dictionary: ' + rootScope.dictionary.pageTitles.logIn);
            console.log('rootScope.pageTitle: ' + rootScope.pageTitle);
            expect(rootScope.pageTitle).toBe('LOG IN');
            // expect(true).toBe(false);
            done();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is pretty obvious - your test is failing because the code `...` is not running.

```
$rootScope.$watch('dictionary', function(dictionary) {
    if (dictionary) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Most probably the problem is in `$rootScope.dictionary` being `undefined` due to not being explicitly set for testing purposes.

Try this

```
describe('setPageTitle()', function() {
    it('should update the $rootScope.pageTitle', function() {
        scope.setPageTitle('logIn');
        rootScope.dictionary = {
            'whatever you': 'need here'
        };
        scope.$apply();
        expect(rootScope.pageTitle).toBe('LOG IN');
    });
});
```

And by the way - there is absolutely no need in using async test case, as `$digest` will be invoked syncronously at `scope.$apply();` line.

Comment: Obvious to someone who is more experienced with unit testing maybe. I'm just getting into this so I'll take that. But please do remember things are not always obvious to everybody.... However, thanks for the thought train, that looks like a great solution. Now that you've pointed it out to me, I can see that it should solve the issue. In my newbie status to unit testing I thought that the angular files loaded and ran when the test started, and all that assignment to the `$rootScope` is done in the `run` block of the app, so I assumed it would be there for the test.

Comment: Well, I said obvious because it was pretty dang obvious. Next time take a more consistent approach to problem solving - start from the end (`$rootScope.pageTitle` is undefined) and begin your investigation from there, checking each place that affects the result. You'll see that it's not that hard. And lastly, you really shouldn't store anything in the `$rootScope`, angular has services for that matter.

Comment: Also, your module does not actually initialize in tests. Karma is just importing all the files you speciefied and that's it. Thus you get all your definitions but no bootstrapping of a module, so the run block never runs. Now, if you had a manual `angular.bootsrap` in one of your files that would be a different story, but you shouldn't need it for simple unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test is a synchronous test, and therefore Karma thinks it's done as soon as the function returns.  Unfortunately, this isn't actually the case since you need to wait around for the affects of the `$apply` to occur, which takes another pass through the event loop.  You'll want to turn your test into an asynchronous test by adding a `done` parameter and calling it somehow after your watch has been triggered.

```
it('description', function(done) {
    // do your setup things here
    scope.$apply();

    setTimeout(function() {
        // make your assertions here
        done()
    }, 25);
})
```

Of course, using `setTimeout` is a pretty ugly way to wait the necessary time, and if there's some other event you can watch for, it would be more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your suggestion but it's still not working, please take a look at my edit in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Few small changes done on your test case, you can give a try for this,

```
 describe('setPageTitle()', function() {

 it('should update the $rootScope.pageTitle', function() {
      rootScope.dictionary = "someValue"; // As you were watching this object assign some value and then apply $digest

      // Instead of $apply use $digest with rootscope
      rootscope.$digest();
      expect(rootScope.pageTitle).toBe('LOG IN');
});
});
```